# Difference between a 'class diagram' and a 'design class diagram'

Tags: uml, class-diagram

I have an assignment that states the following criteria:

```
For this view you may use a truncated version of 
your Design Class Diagram (DCD) including 
only the architecturally significant classes.
```

For context, this is for the Logical View of a 4 + 1 Architectural View. How does a design class diagram (DCD) differ from a regular class diagram? Is it the UML diagram without the functions or variables included (i.e. just the names of the classes and their interactions with each other)?

Comment: They're one and the same...

Comment: Have worked only on class diagram . THe later term is new to me as well .

Comment: @Jordão, What would be the truncated version then?

Comment: The _truncated_ version, as already spelled out, is the version that doesn't show all details of the design, only the most _architecturally significant_ parts...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of the time, people model their code. That's good! In that case, class diagram modeling is used to graphically represent the structure of (object-oriented) classes: class, method, attribute, annotations with stereotypes. Imagine all the JPA, Spring, whatever annotations in the class diagram of a JPA-J2EE based architecture...

As it's said above, the "design class diagram" should only design your domain model, from an architecture level. What are the basic entities your structural system rely on?
No details about the programming language, no "dto", "dao" or technical stuff like that. 
Here's a good example I use: [online shopping cart domain model](http://app.genmymodel.com/class-diagram/examples/Online-Shopping-Cart). It only contains the  *architecturally significant classes*.

HTH, Tom

Comment: Isn't it a contradiction to say it's good to model the code vs. the "design class diagram" should only design your domain model? The class model should resonate with the domain, not the code containing all the technical goo, such as DTOs, DAOs, and made-up classes that exist for the convenience of the programmer.

Comment: isn't DCD is only classes and their relations with other classes without attributes and methods?

Answer (score 1):

Still its amibigous to understand. The main difference between analysis class diagrams and design class diagram is the analysis phase focus on designing a class diagram without concerning about the implementation detail. where as, desgin modelling concern with the implementaion and architechture since, it the high-level static view of the system.